# Dúvida a respeito da inicialização de uma struct em C++

Tags: c++, construtor

Estou tentando inicializar um objeto da struct `Sphere` em C++, que contém como atributos vetores denominados `nm::float3`. Quando eu inicializo o vetor em uma variável e passo ao construtor da struct `Sphere` tudo funciona normal. Caso eu tente colocar o construtor de `nm::float3` diretamente no construtor de `Sphere` o Visual Studio acusa o seguinte erro: `No instance of constructor matches the argument list argument types are: (nm::float3, nm::float3, float)`. Oque estou fazendo de errado? C++ não funciona dessa maneira?

Aqui está a struct `Sphere`:

```
struct Sphere {
    nm::float3 center;
    nm::float3 color;
    float radius;

    Sphere(nm::float3 &center, nm::float3 &color, float radius) 
    : center(center), color(color), radius(radius) {}
};
```

Aqui está minha tentativa de inicialização:

```
nm::float3 center1 = nm::float3(10, 0, 10);
nm::float3 color1 = nm::float3(0, 0, 1);
    
Sphere sphere1 = { center1, color1, 0.5f }; // funciona, sem erros
Sphere sphere2 = { nm::float3(10, 0, 10), nm::float3(0, 0, 1), 0.5f }; // acusando erro
```

Comment: Acho que aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972855/creating-a-new-object-and-passing-in-method-parameter tem a resposta do que você pergunta, mas é um problema de como o C++ gera a referência de um objeto quando você instancia uma classe / estrutura.

Comment: poste algo compilavel, completo.  ajude os outros a ajudarem você

Comment: mais completo que isso? acho que a única coisa que falta é colocar a biblioteca de cálculos matemáticos que estou usando, de resto é jogar essa struct e o código de baixo na main. Mas já descobri a resposta, grato pela grande ajuda :)

Comment: sim, Mais completo que isso. Objetivamente algo que se possa compilar. Grato pela grande e quase completa pergunta. Faltou só o exemplo minimamente compilável